# Multiple criteria conditional formatting in a PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

Can you apply conditional formatting comparing multiple criteria (e.g. two pivot table columns)?

I have a PivotTable in Excel 2013 that compares variable percentage rates and their corresponding values. I want to apply conditional formatting to the PivotTable by highlighting each cell that is greater than the adjacent percentage rate in red, and less than in green. My goal is to apply the formatting to all cells in the column so that I can apply filters.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column to be highlighted and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
 =G1>F1 with red colour
 =G1<F1 with green colour
```

leaves equal values without highlighting. If bothered by highlighting of column label or other cells, select a cell without formatting and Copy, Paste Special, Formats over the top of those.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me locate a solution. I started my new rule, in the pivot table. Then after creating the rule, I selected "Apply Rule To: All cells showing [pivot table value]. Everything is working perfectly. Thanks again!